# Determining the radius or diameter of a Minimum Bounding Circle

Tags: postgresql, postgis

If I have an MBC that looks like the following query:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(geom)::geometry) AS Circle
FROM "Regions"
```

I'm wondering how I can easily determine it's radius. I've resorted to finding the centroid of the circle, at which point I can attempt to calculate the distance between one of the points in the MBCs returned polygon against the centroid however I can't seem to grab just one vertex from the polygon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ST_MinimumBoundingCircle` is a user-contributed function with source written in PL/pgSQL. You can [modify the source](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/713f387f84ae40b6ee96f5db6d7577ddcb93c692/postgis/postgis.sql.in#L5303-5415) as a renamed function `ST_MinimumBoundingRadius(inputgeom geometry)` with these modifications:

- Only needs one argument `inputgeom geometry`
- Change return type (near top) from `geometry` to `double precision`
- For POINT types, change `RETURN hull;` to `RETURN 0;`
- Remove the `ST_Buffer` statement near the end, and just return the `radius`.

Should be easy. Be aware there are some problems with the algorithm, such as [ticket #2996](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2996).

Answer (score 0):

I devised a solution that is simple however perhaps not very efficient. For my purposes it works well.

```
SELECT
    ROUND(
        ST_Distance_Sphere(
            ST_Centroid(ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(geom)),
            ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(geom)), 1)
        ) / 1000
    ) AS radius,
    ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Centroid(geom)) AS center
FROM
    "Regions"
```

The result ends up being a radius in km and the centroid.