# Minimum Bounding Circle in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any existing method for generating the equivalent of a PostGIS ST_MinimumBoundingCircle (see https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MinimumBoundingCircle.html)?

This would be immensely useful for the generation of georeferences using the Point-Radius Method following the recently published Georeferencing Quick Reference Guide (https://doi.org/10.35035/e09p-h128).

Comment: You could try implementing Welzl's algorithm with SQL scripting, but I don't think that's going to be scalable. Better bet is to find/modify a JS implementation and go w/ UDF.

Comment: Bigquery doesn't bring any function that can afford this PostGIS method, as was mentioned in the previous post, you may consider write own JS code in [UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#javascript-udf-examples) to achieve the desired result. Does it sound reasonable for you?

Comment: Thanks. I realize that BigQuery doesn't currently include such a method and that writing a UDF for the purpose is an option. Since there are so many other PostGIS functions implemented I thought this one might be an option for implementation as well, so I am expressing my interest in that. In the meantime, if anyone has Welzl's or any other algorithm implemented in JS, I'd be interested in that.

Comment: There is another question with an answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501009/determining-the-radius-or-diameter-of-a-minimum-bounding-circle), would it help you?